# Using Google Cloud Platform for personal use?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

I've been learning a lot about GCP lately and am starting to think about using this for some personal things such as

- Firestore as a personal database for automated daily logs of personal stats (habits, finances, weight, etc).
- Using cloud storage as long term storage of backups and other personal files
- Cloud functions to interact with my iOS shortcuts

From my calculations the free tiers of these products would last me a very very long time, and if I ever do have to start paying for the services it would be pretty cheap. I would also have a cloud function to pull my billing account in case of being hacked and racking up a huge bill.

Is it okay to use GCP for personal use or am I missing something? I don't want to go down this path if it will be problematic.

Comment: Provided that you accept/respect `Google Cloud Platform Terms of Service` and `Google Cloud Platform Acceptable Use Policy`, Google does not prevent usage based upon the type of customer (individual/business).  https://cloud.google.com/terms https://cloud.google.com/terms/aup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no restriction as such that prevents you from using for personal use. So you can keep using it for free until you hit the [limit](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-tier-usage-limits).